# Как закешировать все файлы js?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-grid

У меня есть скрапер объявлений с hh.ru, пользуюсь selenium. Для того чтобы получить контактные данные объявления ему нужно нажимать на кнопку, из-за этого страница грузит долго, и соответственно скрапер становится супер медленным. Как в selenium сделать так, чтобы кешировались все js файлы или хотя бы те которы мне нужны. Могу предоставить код, но думаю в этом нет необходимости так как скорее всего там нужна какая-то команда, о я прошерстил интрнет и ничего не нашел.

Comment: Вам долго отвечает сервер. Кеширование js - файлов не поможет.

Comment: Заведите свою прокси и ходите через неё, кэшируйте в ней. Были вроде какие-то простенькие прокси с настройками, только уже названия не помню. Proxomitron что ли, например.

Comment: @S.H. Когда отключаю js полностью, все работает очень быстро, но javascript нужен чтобы работала кнопка показать контакты.

Comment: Да, потому что каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку "контакты" страница обращается к серверу за информацией. И просиходит это благодаря js-движку в браузере через rest api. И в hh.ru не дураки сидят, у них наверняка прикручены разные "ограничители частоты запросов". Так что вас спасет только сканирование множеством потоков через ряд прокси